# FastAPI: Returning a List[ReadSchema] as another schema

Tags: python, backend, fastapi, pydantic

I have a `CategoryEnum`:

```py
from enum import Enum

class CategoryEnum(str, Enum):
    A = "A"
    B = "B"
```

I have two tables, `Category` and `Project` tables:

```
from app.enums import CategoryEnum
from sqlmodel import SQLModel

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from app.models.project_model import Project

class Category(SQLModel, table=True):
    __table_name__ = 'category'
    id: Optional[int] = Field(
        primary_key=True,
        index=True,
        nullable=False,
    )
    category: str
    project_id: Optional[int] = Field(
        default=None, foreign_key='project.id', nullable=False)

class Project(SQLModel, table=True):
    __table_name__ = 'project'
    id: Optional[int] = Field(
        primary_key=True,
        index=True,
        nullable=False,
    )
    categories: List[Category] = Relationship(
        back_populates='project',
        sa_relationship_kwargs={
            "lazy": "selectin",
            'cascade': 'all,delete,delete-orphan',
            "primaryjoin": "category.project_id==project.id",
        })
```

I have two schemas which are currently like this:

```
class ICategoryRead(BaseModel):
    category: CategoryEnum

class IProjectRead(BaseModel):
    categories: List[ICategoryRead]
```

In FastAPI, when getting a `Project` record, the `categories` field of `Project` looks like this:

```
"categories": [
          {
            "category": "A"
          },
          {
            "category": "B"
          }
        ],
```

How do I edit the `ICategoryRead` schema such that the output is:

```
"categories": ["A", "B"],
```

Comment: Could you please add your endpoint code ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem comes from the `session.execute` result.

I suppose that you have something like this:

```
statement = select(Category)
reviews = session.execute(statement).all()
```

If you change the select statement to:

```
statement = select(Category.category)
reviews = session.execute(statement).all()
```

you will get the desired result.